# Why doesn't the Django formset appear?

Tags: html, django

I have one form and one formset on the same page. Prior to my deletion of information from django admin, I could see both the form and the formset. After I deleted some 'patient' information and updated my css file, the formset stopped showing.

views.py

```
def patient_new(request):
    patientForm = PatientForm()
    formset = LocationFormSet()
    if request.method == "POST":
        patientForm = PatientForm(request.POST)
        formset = LocationFormSet(request.POST) 
        if patientForm.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
            patient = patientForm.save(commit=True)
            for form in formset:
                location = form.save(commit=False)
                location.patient = patient
                location.save()
            return index(request)
        else:
            print('ERROR FORM INVALID')

    return render(request, 'covidapp/patient_new.html',{'patientForm':patientForm, 'formset':formset})
```

html file

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="row spacer">
            <div class="col-2">
                <div class="input-group">
                    {{ patientForm.as_p }}       
                </div>
            </div> 
        </div> 
    {{ formset.management_form }}
    {% for form in formset %}
    <div class="row form-row spacer">
        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="input-group">
                {{ form.as_p }}
                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success add-form-row">+</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}

    <div class="row spacer">
        <div class="col-4 offset-2"></div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Create</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

html output

[image]

I am not sure whether the hidden input is supposed to be my formset and why it is hidden.

model.py

```
class Patient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    idn = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()
    date_of_confirm = models.DateField()
    case_number = models.IntegerField()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("patient_detail", kwargs={'pk':self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Location(models.Model):
    patient = models.ForeignKey(Patient, related_name='locations', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    location_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True)
    grid_x = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    grid_y = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    date_from = models.DateField(null=True)
    date_to = models.DateField(null=True)
    details = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.location_name
```

form.py

```
class PatientForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Patient
        fields = '__all__'

LocationFormSet = modelformset_factory(
    Location,
    extra=0,
    exclude = ('patient',)
)
```

Comment: How should the form look like? Also, what's the purpose of the form? Edit?

Comment: The form is just a modelformset_factory object with supposedly 9 input fields inherited from the model. I will add the model and form to the question.

Comment: Thank you. Is that a form meant to edit / update existing content?

Comment: No sir. It is just means to add new data. So the form takes patient information. The formset takes in location details the patient has been. Since there can be multiple places a patient could be, I used a formset to dynamically add new forms to the formset.

Comment: With `extra = 0` you don't have any form in your formset if you're creating new data. So you should use at least `extra=1` so that one form appears. And have javascript create extra forms if you need to add more than 1 location.

Comment: As you can see `TOTAL_FORMS` is 0. You could also create an 'add location' button that creates the form but it's easier to have at least one to start (that you can copy with javascript).

Comment: This actually worked. The interesting part is, in the beginning of my project I would have 2 forms if extra was 1. That was the reason why I set the extra to 0. But thank you.